# Silent install of sql server 2017 failing

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, powershell

I have downloaded the sql server express edition 2017, and want to automate its install through Powershell. Keep in mind because it is express, it doesn't have a configuration file. After downloading I have to manually extract the folder by running that exe file, which contains the actual SETUP.EXE inside. Finally, I try to do a silent install, but it fails with a 0x84B40003 error.

What I've done is:

```
// Download the file from the Microsoft website
$url = "https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=853017"
$output = "C:\Users\sysadmin\mySql.exe"
$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.DownloadFile($url, $output)

// Manually extract the folder containing the SETUP.EXE

// Try to do a silent install
"C:\Users\sysadmin\Downloads\SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU\SETUP.EXE" -ArgumentList "/s" -Wait
```

The last step fails with the following

### : TITLE: SQL Server Setup failure.

SQL Server Setup has encountered the following error:

The setting 'S' specified is not recognized.

Error code 0x84B40003.

Comment: why do you need to install it silently? you still need to setup the sql administrator.

Comment: @maSTAShuFu Is it possible to pass the credentials for the sql administrator in the silent install parameters?

Comment: no idea as i don't do silent install

Comment: Have you read through the docs? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server-from-the-command-prompt it seems like you are missing a lot of parameters here. There's a specific article on powershell too: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powersql/2017/10/10/install-sql-server-2017-using-powershell-desired-state-configuration/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-ArgumentList` is not a parameter for SQL's `SETUP.EXE` program. That's a PowerShell parameter for the `Start-Process` cmdlet. I don't think you need to try so hard.

```
C:\Users\sysadmin\Downloads\SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU\SETUP.EXE /s
```

i.e., just put the executable name on the command line, followed by the arguments you want. In PowerShell, if the executable's path or filename contains spaces, enclose it in quotes and invoke it with the `&` operator; e.g.:

```
& "C:\Path with spaces\SETUP.EXE" /s
```

However, it is likely that just the `/s` parameter is insufficient for a fully-unattended installation. For that you will need to consult the documentation. This answer is intended to clarify a basic misunderstanding of running executables in PowerShell - just run them.